# C# Exception: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference while checking whether it is null or not

Tags: c#, exception, null

I simply need to check whether the object is not null before actually using it but it keeps throwing this exception:
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

```
if (interMarket.marketItems.prices != null) {
// do something..
}
```

`interMarket` contains data from JSON.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `interMarket` has an element named `marketItems`, which in turn has an element named `prices`, and that all of them are populated?

Comment: Can you show more code ? is it mvc application ? can you show code from the view and javascript ?

Comment: you need to show the code that made intermarket.xxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What specific exception is being thrown? Where is it being thrown in your code? Is it possible that interMarket or interMarket.marketItems is null? If so, using the null conditional operator (?.) will fix the issue:

```
if (interMarket?.marketItems?.prices != null) {
// do something..
}
```

Comment: Yes, you were right. The JSON object is too complex to ensure that even interMarket.marketItems is not null. This works!! Tnx a lot!!

Comment: @Totallama I'm glad I could help!